In Bereshit 1:1, are the plurals in השּׁמים significant, or plural in form (ie: "skies") but singular in meaning (ie: "sky"), and how do we determine?
Disclaimer: I don't know Hebrew.
In Bereshit 1:1, are the plurals in השּׁמים significant, or plural in form (ie: "skies") but singular in meaning (ie: "sky"), and how do we determine?

There's no singular form of שמים. It's like the word מים for water, lit. "waters."

As I suspected. Can you please post that as an answer? Thanks.

But there's another word for "sky" - רקיע, which can be and is used in the plural form. שמים is often used in the more abstract sense, like "heaven." But רקיע means the literal sky.

That's very helpful info also. Do you have an example (ie: address) for שמים ?

See Genesis 28:17, Deuteronomy 26:15, Deuteronomy 32:40. It's also ubiquitous in common terms like יראת שמים (fear of heaven) and מן השמים ([ordained] from heaven).

Excellent, thank you very much, @shmosel.

Hmm... consulting Gesenius and the various usages, it appears to refer to the raqqia as well. ?

Yes, they're often (usually?) synonymous.

@shmosel why not combine your comments into an answer?

@EdwardB I often ask myself that very question.

@shmosel Rakia means the firmament - see Psohim 94 - which by God's plan, divides upper waters from lower waters It has windows through heavy which rain is poured (see the flood story). In Hebrew, the expression רקיע השמים means rakia of Shamayim, those are two different things.
